# Rails 3.2 ActiveRecord Session Store Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session, activerecord

I'm migrating my application from Rails 3.0.12 to 3.2. I use the active_record_store to work with my session variables, owing the size limits on the default cookie store. On the new version of Rails, however, the session variable is not getting set.

I can see that the cookie session_id is being set with a value, but I can look at the contents of the database and see no values being inserted when a session variable is supposed to be populated.

However, if I switch back to cookie store, it works fine. Is there anything I can check to find out what's going on?

Comment: please cross verify various instructions given here - http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SessionStore

Comment: can you please add configuration code from application.rb/development.rb, or paste session table schema or other associated code, and/or any log error if you see

Comment: Do consider that sessions are meant to be lightweight objects, and if your app takes any amount of traffic, DB-backed session store will likely to become a bottleneck quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid the problem solved itself, perhaps in a Gem update that I performed in preparing to respond to the comments on this question. I had the Rails 3.2 version of my app on a separate Git branch, so I brought it back and merged it with my current development version.... and it all "just works".

I can't help but think this was a transient issue with either an older version of my code or a gem, but it's solved now, so I'll close this question.